# How can I find out what memcache returns result ? (Yii 1)

Tags: yii, memcached

I use memcache, cofigurated it in config. All work fine, but i think data always returns from db, not from cache.
In CDBCommand 495 string:

```
if(($result = $cache->get($cacheKey)) !== false) {                         
    var_dump('test'); die;
    Yii::trace('Query result found in cache', 'system.db.CDbCommand');
    return $result[0];
}
```

But `$result` always is `FALSE`.
This query I use:

```
$result = Yii::app()
            ->db
            ->cache(100)
            ->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wo_users')
            ->queryRow();
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Where do you `$cache->set(...`?

Comment: Are you sure the `die;` in your first code block isn't mistake? Also pls provide lines before `if(($result = $cache->get($cacheKey)) !== false) {`